# 'centralityPlot(network)' did not print betweenness and closeness

Tags: r, r-qgraph

Centrality data printed fine but the centrality plot command produced only a strength plot. There was no plot for closeness or betweenness -- how do I obtain the latter two?

I'm walking through the Costatini et al (2015) tutorial using RStudio with the supplied data: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092656614000701

R & qgraph newbie working in RStudio.

centrality <- centrality_auto(network) 
centrality

nc <- centrality$node.centrality 
nc

ebc <- centrality$edge.betweenness.centrality
ebc

centralityPlot(network)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your question. From Japan.

```
centralityPlot(network, include = c("Strength", "Betweenness", "Closeness"))
```